# Matching periodicity Fama-French Factors, Portfolio Return and Risk Free rate

Tags: returns, fama-french, risk-free, abnormal-returns

I am trying to replicate certain aspects of the following paper: ["Does the stock market fully value intangibles? Employee satisfaction and equity prices" - Alex Edmans (2011)](http://faculty.london.edu/aedmans/Rowe.pdf) for three European countries (GER, FR, UK).

I am interested in replicating the following regression (1) and I am particularly interested in the $\alpha$:

$$R_{t} = \alpha + \beta _{MKT}MKT_{t} + \beta _{HML}HML_{t} + \beta _{SMB}SMB_{t} + \beta _{MOM}MOM_{t} + \varepsilon_{it}$$

- $R_{t}$: the return on Portfolio I in month t in excess of a risk-free rate
- $\alpha$: intercept that captures the abnormal risk-adjusted return
- $MKT_{t}, HML_{t}, SMB_{t},MOM_{t}$:the monthly returns on the market, value, size, and momentum factors **for Europe**, taken from [Ken French’s Web site](http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/data_library.html#Developed) under the "Developed Markets Factors and Returns" section.

I am not sure whether I am comparing apples and oranges here. To calculate the individual components I have done the following:

- for $R_{t}$ I have used monthly price data and calculated the monthly returns (i.e. from one month to the next), which I have then used to calculate a **monthly** portfolio return.
- The paper states that I should subtract the risk-free rate from the PF returns, therefore I downloaded on a monthly frequency the 10year government bond returns from Bloomberg for Germany, France and the UK respectively. I understand that those rates are **annual** rates. *Am I correct to assume that I would have to divide those rates by 12 in order to obtain **monthly** risk-free rates that I can subtract from my PF returns?*
- In the [Excel file](http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/ftp/Europe_3_Factors_CSV.zip) from Kenneth French's website, the $MKT$ variable is reported as "Mkt-Rf", "SMB", "HML" and "Rf". Hence, my understanding is that if I wanted to use my own (country-specific) risk-free rate, I could add-up "Mkt-Rf" and "Rf" and then subtract the country-specific 10-year gov-bond rates. Here I am not sure however, how to read those Fama-French factors and whether I would need to subtract the **monthly** or **annual** risk-free rate. *Do the reported Fama-French factors need to be adjusted to match the **monthly** portfolio returns as well?*

*So to sum up, is my approach of using the **monthly** PF returns in excess of the **monthly** (and hopefully correctly broken-down) risk-free rate compatible with using the Fama-French Factors (**monthly or yearly?**) feasible?*

I hope that this makes my problem clear - however, if this is not the case I will happily provide further information.

Thank you in advance for your time and help!

Comment: Regarding the last question, you certainly need to convert an annualized risk-free to monthly rate and then subtract from the monthly (raw) Market returns.

Comment: a risk-free rate is also a return (one on a risk-free investment), and hence has frequency among its dimensions (return *per month* in fractions of 1 etc.); just do the dimensional analysis on both sides of your regression equation, and everything will become clear.